chose files random and put the names into textfiles
in a folder are files from file1 to fileX.
X is for sometimes it goes from file1 to file21.
and sometimes it goes from file1 to file55.
how to run a script or a one liner to create 4 groups (A-D) / 4 lists
filegroupA.txt
filegroupB.txt
filegroupB.txt
filegroupD.txt
but the filenames should pick up random and unsorted into the .txt-files
filegroupA.txt
file2
file18
file7
file13
file4
...

filegroupB.txt
...
edit:
the names have no special characters.
they are all with the same scheme, fileX and fileXX.
there are no subdirectorys too.
the minimum output for a filegroupX-file must be 4.
there are never fewer than 20 fileXX files.
the uppercase A-D labelling is not a strict requirement, its only for better reading, but not a must-have feature.

Have you tried anything yourself? I would suggest (a) List the filenames with a shell expansion, ls, or find (being careful that your names have no special characters, and your pattern does not match any subdirectory). (b) Pass that list through shuf. (c) Use awk to write to the output files in turn using NR % 4 to index a target filename. split might be an alternative there, but the options are unforgiving.

If you have any requirement for how many file names each of your 4 output files should contain (e.g. given 10 input files can 1 output file contain 7 of them and the other 3 output files 1 each?) then add that to your question. Also provide a minimal complete example, i.e. an input file with some number of lines and 4 output files showing possible output given that input. Get rid of any ...s from your example, they just clutter it.

@EdMorton  Good point. I assumed a near-even round-robin distribution. Interesting random case where a file gets no entries

@Paul_Pedant Right. What if the input directory has fewer than 4 files? Can file names contain newlines? Should directories be skipped? etc... Lots of opportunities for the OP to provide more requirements :-).

My instinct is to create the four empty output files up front, so as to not break anything downstream, but it needs to be a specific stated requirement. I did discover that awk printf ("") > "Name"  creates an empty file, and leaves it open for additional data.

Is the uppercase A-D labeling of the output files a strict requirement? Otherwise you could do something simple with the split command e.g. printf '%s\n' file* | split -n r/4 - filegroup or printf '%s\n' file* | split -n r/4 --additional-suffix=.txt - filegroup

the names have no special characters, they are all with the same scheme, fileX and fileXX. there are no subdirectorys too. the minimum output for a filegroupX-file must be 4. there are never fewer than 20 fileXX files. the uppercase A-D labeling is not a strict requirement, its only for better reading, but not a musthave feature.

IOW, you want to partition the files in a given directory randomly into 4 lists, each list having at least 4 files (so there must be at least 4*4 = 16 files in the directory), and the lists themselves having files in a random order?

This problem is so unrealistically restricted that it looks like a Homework Problem.

Could be:
export MIN_PER_FILE=4 FILES='filegroupA.txt filegroupB.txt filegroupC.txt filegroupD.txt'
ls path/to/the/folder | shuf | awk '
  BEGIN{
    n = split(ENVIRON["FILES"], file)
    srand()
  }
  {print > file[NR <= n * ENVIRON["MIN_PER_FILE"] ? NR % n + 1 : int(rand() * n + 1)]}'

Where we shuffle the list of file, despatch the first MIN_PER_FILE*n lines into the n files to guarantee there are at least MIN_PER_FILE in each (provided there are enough files), and then for the rest despatch at random between the n files.
If your system doesn't have shuf, it might have sort -R.
